# How high in ABV can a beer be before the yeast is too stressed to re-use?

Tags: reusing-yeast

I've recently taken advantage of White Labs switch to year-round availability of WLP090, as this rocket fuel of a yeast strain is very attenuative, very clean, fast, and floccuates beautifully.  I love it.

I just brewed a wonderful double IPA ([recipe is here](http://www.bertusbrewery.com/2013/04/ipa-clone-series-stone-enjoy-by-ipa.html), seriously, go brew this beer), using two vials of WLP090 in a whopping starter, and the trub/yeast at the bottom of this carboy is massive.  I would have enough yeast to be set for months.  Problem is, it's ~10-11% ABV (attenuated past the 9.4% I expected, I won't complain).  [White Lab's description of the yeast](http://www.whitelabs.com/yeast/wlp090-san-diego-super-yeast) says that it's alcohol tolerance is "high", so I assume it can take a beating past the typical 13%, but I doubt that I want to push it up towards it's limits before washing it.

Is there a general rule of thumb, a safe percent of alcohol by volume for when the yeast is just too stressed to wash and re-use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ROT is to not reuse yeast from an OG higher than 1.060.  I've succesfully pushed that to 1.073.  That assumes a healthy pitchin the first place.  I've also taken a bit of slurry from a higher OG and used it o make a new starter.  At the OG of your beer, I'd be leery.  You should use some to make a starter and carefully assess its health before using it.

Comment: I suspected that any beer starting with the words "Double", "Imperial", "Russian", or any mix of those together would mean the yeast is toast.  Thanks for the verification.

Comment: Coincidentally I just read [this](http://byo.com/blogs/entry/yeast-a-lover-not-a-fighter) today. The author attempted to harvest the yeast from a bottle-conditioned 11% ABV beer. He was not able to culture the yeast due to the cells being non-viable.

Comment: I've read that same article.  I saw another video on youtube recently where someone was able to successfully reuse that same yeast (from Heady Topper's The Alchemist), pulling from an 8% ABV beer.  Even at that point though, it took him a couple of days to see any activity in his starter.  I don't know if I'd trust the yeast past one fermentation at that rate.

Answer (score 0):

German author Hagen Rudolph claims to have brewed a 25% ABV beer (http://www.hagenrudolph.de/Dokumente/Superstarkbier.pdf (in German)) with WLP099 (http://www.whitelabs.com/yeast/wlp099-super-high-gravity-ale-yeast).

Comment: I can't read German, but I am well aware (by experience) of WLP099.  Does White Lab's high gravity yeast allow for a higher tolerance before it isn't worth it to re-use the yeast?